# Having trouble installing LogicalDoc Community--cannot unzip install file

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, zip

I am having trouble installing the free version of LogicalDoc, using the instructions in the text file and on [their wiki](http://wiki.logicaldoc.com/wiki/Quick_Install#Setup_Procedure).  I've downloaded the .zip, but unzipping it is proving problematic.  The unzip command returns an error:

> $ unzip logicaldoc-community-installer-7.6.4.zip
> unzip:  cannot find or open logicaldoc-community-installer-7.6.4.zip, logicaldoc-community-installer-7.6.4.zip.zip or logicaldoc-community-installer-7.6.4.zip.ZIP.

I also tried unzipping it w/o using the terminal, but then the next instruction (Execute the command /Library/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start to run LogicalDOC + Tomcat application server.) doesn't work either because no directory has been created.  **Also**, following the .txt instructions doesn't work:

> $ sudo java -jar logicaldoc-installer.jar
> [sudo] password for jen:
> Error: Unable to access jarfile logicaldoc-installer.jar

- JDK8 installed properly.
- Here is the link to the text file instructions: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24401948/

Comment: Usually, these kinds of errors are a result of not navigating to the directory that contains the zipfile first (e.g. `cd ~/Downloads` or wherever you downloaded `logicaldoc-community-installer-7.6.4.zip` to)

Comment: @steeldriver I tried doing that, but I get the same error.   And when I double-click the .deb, nothing happens.  I get the timer spinner on my mouse, but otherwise, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try with version 7.7.1 of LogicalDOC Community
https://sourceforge.net/projects/logicaldoc/files/distribution/LogicalDOC%20CE%207.7/logicaldoc-community-installer-7.7.1.zip/download

1. get the zip with the installer
2. uncompress it
3. open a command shell and cd to that directory
4. launch the command: sudo su
5. launch the command: java -jar logicaldoc-installer.jar
6. proceed with the installation steps

Note: you need an Ubuntu with a Desktop (GUI), because that is a graphical installer. If you doesn't have one, add the parameter -console to the command

```
java -jar logicaldoc-installer.jar -console
```

See also the installation of LogicalDOC Enterprise on Ubuntu https://youtu.be/Al2Pi5e1wi0

Or else https://www.unixmen.com/setup-logicaldoc-ubuntu-15-04/